# getting collisions in gazebo plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, collision, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm writing a world plug-in and I would like some event to happen when two specific models collide.

My problem is that I don't see the appropriate methods to do this in the gazebosim.org documentation.  I can get the world pose and write my own collision detection, but shouldn't this already be happening?  How do I get access to the collisions of a model (if any)?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39054/getting-collisions-in-gazebo-plugin/) by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, if you're looking to check for contact between models, the first thing that pops into my head is the `gazebo_ros_bumper` gazebo plugin. You can find the source code [here](http://devel.iri.upc.edu/docs/roswiki/doc/diamondback/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__bumper_8cpp_source.html) if you want to look through it. That might provide you with a good starting point.

When I was looking to detect collision, I simply made my robot a gigantic bump sensor. That allowed me to subscribe to the bumper topic and find collisions that way. It's not the most efficient method, but it was a quick fix for me.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcevoyandy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2166/mcevoyandy/) on 2012-07-27**:
Looks like I might have to go this way too, can't seem to find a good way to do what I'd like inside of a plug-in.  Thanks for the suggestion.